# como puedo hacer para pasar un request xml con un metodo con punto a php?

Tags: php, xml

tengo un problema, es que no se como puedo hacer para realizar la petición de este xml ya que el método tiene un punto:

metodo: create.form

este es el resultado por soat y php:

```
$result = $client->create.form( $p );
```

colocando el punto en el metodo php ya no funciona

Comment: has probado a asignar el metodo en una cadena y luego indicar la cadena? algo como: `$metodo = 'create.form'; $result = $client->$method($p);` ?

Comment: @Jakala eso no es recomendable...

Comment: necesitas mostrar mas informacion la verdad no entiendo por pque el metodo tiene un punto en el medio... de donde sacaste el metodo o esta declarado... no deberia de usar puntos los metodos... no cumple con ninguna standar php

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 el tema del punto viene debido al comando soap al que está llamando. Fue un estándar hace tiempo en soap separar palabras en los comandos por medio de punto. No es de tema PHP. Lo de añadirlo como cadena y probarlo es funcional en este caso. Luego ya se puede mirar con otros métodos (si existen)

Comment: se pierde trasabilidad en los IDE cuando usas texto como metodo... intenta darle a ir al metodo o algo asi ... y veras que no lo va a encontrar...